# Why the question about gitconfigs is removed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-questions

There was a [good set of advices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267761/what-does-your-gitconfig-contain) about configuring git (I've learned some from them and posted mine things as well), but now I can't find it anywhere in SE (except of on various numerous SE mirrors).

Why is it deleted? Was it that bad?

Comment: (Also I have just found out that my "tumbleweed" SU question about flushing streams to GPG is also deleted and I received no notice...)

Comment: closed as not a real question by Sam Saffron♦ May 3 at 1:49

Comment: deleted by Jeff Atwood♦ May 3 at 1:52

Comment: Why is has not got migrated to Programmers SE for example?

Comment: Because it is not a real question. It is a Poll which is discouraged throughout the whole SE network.

Comment: Where should useful/fun content originated on SE sites go then? Should there be some non-SE site (but "migratable to") where we can put "good, but {offtopic, non-QA, fun}" things?

Comment: @Vi.: Try Reddit.

Comment: Should there be "migrate this to Reddit and close the question, redirecting/linking users to that Reddit thing" feature?

Comment: Vi, are you joking? No.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta, Then what to do with this such content apart from removing it?

Comment: Post it on your blog or something. It's up to you, it's a big wide Internet out there.

Comment: The rules have gotten more stringent around here. My guess is they went through and cleaned a bunch of stuff up. I wish it wasn't deleted but oh well. I wish it was just locked.

Comment: [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such poll type questions are not allowed on Stack Overflow anymore (or for that matter, anywhere else on the network). While I fully understand and agree with all of the reasons given for disallowing such questions, I'm against deleting questions which have *some value* to programmers and this is one among them.

I feel that old questions like this one, which are *directly* related to programming or the use of a programming tool, should be closed as "Not constructive", locked and a shiny "Exists for historical reasons" banner slapped on it (come on, waffles has been working hard on implementing this, so let's use it!).

Let me state that I'm actually even fine with mass deletion *if* there is some standard and guideline in choosing them. **Right now questions are being deleted on whim and others that are even more egregiously off-topic/not constructive are being left alone because of personal preferences and some because it still gives them a chuckle.** These arbitrary exceptions are totally unfair in a community that supposedly sticks to guidelines and faqs. It is extremely hard for the community to delete these questions too, because some of them require nearly 300 votes to delete!

Here's my list of questions that belong on present day Stack Overflow's hall of shame, that for some reason or the other have not been deleted:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192793/what-is-your-favorite-programmer-t-shirt
- [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203286/what-things-didnt-you-know-you-needed-but-are-now-very-glad-you-have
- [C++ blogs that you regularly follow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151974/c-blogs-that-you-regularly-follow)
- [Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662956/most-useful-free-net-libraries
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309300/what-makes-php-a-good-language
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380819/common-programming-mistakes-for-net-developers-to-avoid
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687/keyboard-for-programmers
- [What non-programming books should programmers read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210/what-non-programming-books-should-programmers-read)
- [What do "branch", "tag" and "trunk" mean in Subversion repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-really-mean)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245196/c-urban-myths
- [How do I move the turtle in LOGO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo)
- [Hidden features of Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245395/underused-features-of-windows-batch-files)
- [What are important languages to learn to understand different approaches and concepts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958630/what-are-important-languages-to-learn-to-understand-different-approaches-and-conc)

I think I've made my point clear. **We simply should not accept that a question fair and square on a programming tool (even if "not constructive") is deleted when something about nerdy t-shirts is allowed to remain!** You can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+votes%3A100+is%3Aquestion&submit=search). Delete all of these with *extreme prejudice* or draw up guidelines and stick to them, no matter what your personal preference is. If you're that attached, favorite it and then delete. That way, you can go back to it whenever you want.

Comment: I don't think it's lack of desire to do so, it's just that there are over 2 million questions, and handling them all takes time. see also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/

Comment: While there maybe 2 million questions, you can easily narrow them down with `wiki:1 votes:100 is:question`. There are only 278 such questions as of now. On [so], each tag (primary tags/language tags) functions as its own little community and couldn't care less about what happens to the rest. I certainly do not think that users of C# or ASP.NET or Java could gauge if a top voted big-list question is utterly useless in say, R or Haskell or Mathematica. In smaller communities in more specialized languages, such list questions are of _immense_ help in going forward (continued... )

Comment: ... because there aren't that many good resources available easily. So yes, silly favorite blend of coffee type questions should be nuked, but the more programming related ones should be given a good thought before deletion. If the moderator knows enough about the tag that the question is in and still deletes, then fine. If they're unsure, then I believe it should be brought to meta first. Note that I've diverged from the question on hand. I'm talking in more general terms here.

Comment: I can see your point about *obscure* topics, which have a natural limitation of not many people participating or even knowing enough to answer -- but how is "list your personal favorite {insert-very-common-programming-tool-here} config file" anything other than an infinite list of X?

Comment: It certainly is an infinite list of X question and I'm not even arguing that they be allowed. I dislike them and as I said in my post, I fully understand why they should be closed and new ones nuked. All I'm saying is that if it was of use at least to the union of users who upvoted + favorited + x% of viewers and if it's directly related to programming, then perhaps consider just locking it in place. The questions that really need to be targeted are the extremely localized questions which are of _no_ use to anyone else. SO is littered with those because people use it as a personal solver.

Comment: I removed some of the more egregious examples, above. Also you don't need to type `@jeff` because there's nobody else talking here; who else could you possibly be addressing other than me? (in other words, notifications are automatic in this case..)

Comment: I know I don't need to type it, but still do out of habit. Thanks for deleting some of the questions. I'm curious: do you _really_ think the "best comment in source code" question is constructive or even on-topic?

Answer (score 4):

Poll, list, "look what I've got in my pocket, what have you got in yours" questions are off-topic on all the SE sites.

The question you refer to falls into the sub category of:

> *"I use ________ for ________, what do you use?"*

See https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask for more info.

Comment: While I agree with deleting these in principle, I find it totally unfair that a lot of arbitrary, silly and pointless questions are allowed to remain on the site. Please read my answer.